# How to access an array of DocumentReference in flutter?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[image: the reg_events field is an array of references to the events collection.]

I want to access all the reg_events for the currently logged in user. I have the following code right now

```
       stream: Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(email).snapshots(),
       builder: (context, snapshot){
         if(!snapshot.hasData){
           return Text("Loading..");
         }
         return Center(
          child: new Container(
            child: new PageView.builder(
                onPageChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    currentpage = value;
                  });
                },
                controller: controller,
                itemCount: snapshot.data['reg_events'].length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => builder(index, snapshot.data)),
          ),
        );
       }
     ),
```

The 'builder' is:

```
builder(int index, DocumentSnapshot document) {
    return new AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: controller,
      builder: (context, child) {
        double value = 1.0;
        if (controller.position.haveDimensions) {
          value = controller.page - index;
          value = (1 - (value.abs() * .5)).clamp(0.0, 1.0);
        }

        return new Center(
          child: new SizedBox(
            height: Curves.easeOut.transform(value) * 200,
            width: Curves.easeOut.transform(value) * 1000,
            child: child,
          ),
        );
      },
      child: new Card(
        child: Text(document.data['reg_events'][0].toString(),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.white),),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.blue : Colors.red,
      ),
    );
  }
```

But it outputs "Instance of 'DocumentReference'". How do I access this Document Reference?

Comment: Could you include your builder?

Comment: I have updated my post now @pr0gramist

Comment: Can you share how to apply the where condition with reg_events fields.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it not understand **reg_event** as List so try this,

```
 stream: Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(email).snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot){
     List regEvent = new List();
     if(snapshot.hasData){
        regEvent = snapshot.data['reg_events'];
      }
      if(!snapshot.hasData){
        return Text("Loading..");
      }
      return Center(
           child: new Container(
                 child: new PageView.builder(
                         onPageChanged: (value) {
                                setState(() {
                                      currentpage = value;
                                });
                          },
                         controller: controller,
                         itemCount: regEvent.length,
                         itemBuilder: (context, index) { 
                               print(regEvent[index]);
                               return builder(index, snapshot.data)),}
                      ),
               );
         }
),
```

Answer (score 0):

DocumentReference is like a pointer to one document. You can get the single document using `.get` method which returns `Future<DocumentSnapshot>`. Since you have an array of them, you can then use Streams to get a bunch of Futures.

```dart
List<DocumentReference> references = [ref, ref, ref];

var myStream = Stream.fromFutures(references.map((ref) => ref.get()).toList());

StreamBuilder(builder: ..., stream: myStream);
```

But...

Firestore has querying, so it should be better if you actually use it. You should be able to reference your `reg_events` like that:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('users').document("$email/reg_events").snapshots();
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example a User object is created which contains a list of references of the entities (or events). This list is then passed to the DatabaseService class which returns a list of EntityDetails stream objects.

DatabaseService Class:

```
final CollectionReference entityCollection =
      Firestore.instance.collection('entities');
  final CollectionReference userCollection =
      Firestore.instance.collection('user');

 Stream<UserDetails> get userDetails {
    return userCollection
        .document(uid)
        .snapshots()
        .map(_userDetailsFromSnapshot);
  }

UserDetails _userDetailsFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return UserDetails(
        email: snapshot.data['email'],
        phone: snapshot.data['phone'],
        fname: snapshot.data['fname'],
        lname: snapshot.data['lname'],
        streetNr: snapshot.data['street_nr'],
        city: snapshot.data['city'],
        entities: List.from(snapshot.data['entities']));
  }

 List<Stream<EntityDetails>> getEntitiesFromDRList(
      List<DocumentReference> entities) {
    List<Stream<EntityDetails>> elist = new List();
    entities.forEach((element) {
      elist.add(element.snapshots().map((_entityDetailsFromSnapshot)));
    });
    return elist;
  }

EntityDetails _entityDetailsFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
return EntityDetails(
  uid: uid,
  name: snapshot.data['name'],
  description: snapshot.data['description'],
  type: snapshot.data['type'],
  geoPoint: snapshot.data['geopoint'],
  adressString: snapshot.data['adress_string'],
  email: snapshot.data['email'],
  phone: snapshot.data['phone'],
);}
```

Widget

```
stream: DatabaseService(uid: uid).userDetails,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            UserDetails userDetails = snapshot.data;
            //Get the Streams
            DatabaseService(uid: uid)
                .getEntitiesFromDRList(userDetails.entities)
                .forEach((element) {
              element.listen((data) {
                print("DataReceived: " + data.name);
              }, onDone: () {
                print("Task Done");
              }, onError: (error) {
                print("Some Error");
              });
            });
```

User-Object

```
class UserDetails {
  final String email;
  final String phone;
  final String fname;
  final String lname;
  final String streetNr;
  final String city;
  final List<DocumentReference> entities;

  UserDetails(
      {this.email,
      this.phone,
      this.fname,
      this.lname,
      this.streetNr,
      this.city,
      this.entities});
}
```